# How to shorten an array based on condition in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I am a new `bash` learner. I have an array in `bash` taking input from standard input. I have to shorten the array on the basis of some logic. Say, I have the following elements in the array:

```
Namibia
Nauru
Nepal
Netherlands
NewZealand
Nicaragua
Niger
Nigeria
NorthKorea
Norway
```

Now, I have to shorten the array and only the `accepted` elements could remain in the array. One element of the array would be treated as `accepted` if **it does not contain the letter `a`(case-sensitive) and contains the letter `i`(case-insensitive)**. For the above list, the answer would be:

```
Niger
```

How to implement it in `bash`?

Please note that, I can print the array without having condition like the following. but I want to have condition on it.

```
countries=()
while read -r country; do
    countries+=( "$country" )
done
# here i have to do something to shrink/shorten the array on the basis of some logic. In this case, elements of countries should have at least one character 'a' and should not contain 'i' / 'I'.
echo "${countries[@]}"
```

Comment: So what's the problem? What did you try? Are you stuck somewhere?

Comment: I want the ``bash`` code to do the problem. @AlbertoZaccagni

Comment: That will not happen. Stackoverflow is not a site where you go to have others do your work, you are required to show the effort you made to tackle the problem.
Once you've done that I'm sure you will find people willing to help you.

Comment: I have edited my question. I had some work and stuck on how to print or make a new array if there are some conditions. Please note that, it is not any professional work or something. I am a new bash learner and I am a student. It is my curiosity to learn bash, it is even not a part of my academic something. Thanks. @AlbertoZaccagni

Comment: I feel that you could do that without writing a script, but using the tools already provided to you, like grep: `echo $countries | grep i | grep -v a`. For sure that are better ways but this is one. Do you have requirements that forbid you to use tools like `grep`?

Comment: It is giving runtime error. please, have a look on [it](https://ideone.com/IXUyGD) and help me to find the bug. Thanks in advance.  @AlbertoZaccagni

Comment: That's not an error. That's empty output because you only echo:d the first array element because `echo "${countries}"` and `echo "${countries[@]}"` are not the same. That was an error in the suggested command.

Comment: Can you please correct it? @EtanReisner

Comment: I already did. To get the entire array you need to use `"${countries[@]}"` instead of `"$countries"`. In bash `"$countries"` only gets you the first array value (it is identical to `"${countries[0]}"`).

Comment: Where is this data coming from in the first place? A file? The user?

Comment: From the user, not file. Unfortunately [this](https://ideone.com/WUrCHB) is not working. @EtanReisner

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to work since that echo produces one line of output so `grep` is going to exclude it all. You need to either filter in the loop or use `printf '%s\n' "${countries[@]}" | ....`.

Comment: It is working fine. Thank you so much. Could you please post it as the answer of the question so that I can accept it? @EtanReisner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter the list while you are constructing the array you should do something like this:

```
countries=()
while read -r country; do
    country=$(echo "$country" | grep -vi a | grep i)
    if [ -n "$country" ]; then
        countries+=( "$country" )
    fi
done
printf '%s\n' "${countries[@]}"
```